# How to make the left sidebar fixed and always available while scrolling main content using bootstrap js?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a page using bootstrap 3 where i have a left menu and a main content and right menu. My requirement is while scrolling the main content, side menu should be always be visible in the left for the user to select options? Please help me with this.

I tried providing css as "position:fixed" for the div for sidebar which makes the sidebar fixed while scrolling but the main content is overlapping with the sidebar.

Answer (score 1):

Try having a custom base frame like this:

```
// Html
<div class="sidebar">
</div>
<div class="main-content">
</div>

//CSS 

.sidebar {
width: 14%;
display:block;
float:left;
position:fixed;
height:100%;
background: #f7f7f7;
border-right: 1px solid #dae3e9;
padding-top: 2em;
    }
  .main-content {
width: 85.5%;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 14.5%;
 }
```

You can have you bootstrap rows within these frames. Hope this helps....